# puppeteer : wait for ajax call after navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

so in my code i submit a form  , wait for navigation and submit a second form ... here is the tricky part ... before the second from submit some data will be loaded in the from with ajax

i want to wait for those ajax call the be done and then submit the second form

here is a simplified version of my code

```
    await Promise.all([
        page.click('#form1_submit'),
        page.waitForNavigation(),
    ])


    if (!await page.$("#form2_element"))
        throw new Error(' ELEMENT MISSING 2 ');

    await page.$eval('#form2_element', (el, data) => el.value = data.value , data);



    await Promise.all([
        page.click('#form2_submit'),
        page.waitForNavigation(),
    ])
```

after this

```
 await Promise.all([
        page.click('#form1_submit'),
        page.waitForNavigation(),
    ])
```

how can i say wait for ajax calls ? i tried this

```
    await Promise.all([
        page.click('#form1_submit'),
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }),
    ])
```

but it didnt work and for submited before ajax call is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait for data to be displayed after an AJAX call is made, I'll point you towards my answer on this very topic from another thread:

[how to handle elements that load after ajax request in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260812/how-to-handle-elements-that-load-after-ajax-request-in-puppeteer)

Hopefully this helps!