# Puppeteer: wait for Ajax call after page loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, puppeteer

### SOLUTION:

As per @pguardiario 's suggestion, the following intercepts the Ajax call and waits for its completion:

```
  await page.waitForResponse('http://localhost:58080/', {timeout: 2000})
    .catch(() => {console.log('[puppeteer] Error')});
```

---

I have a page which performs an Ajax call after the page has loaded and I need for puppeteer to wait for the completion of that call. In [puppeteer : wait for ajax call after navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283834/puppeteer-wait-for-ajax-call-after-navigation) the accepted answer uses `await page.waitForSelector(cssSelector);` which doesn't work in my current case since the success of the Ajax call doesn't add any new elements to the page. Here's a minimal working example with some comments as to what the actual page does:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // render data previously stored in localStorage
      console.log('Fetching page');
      // in reality it is fetching a JSON API endpoint, but for the purposes of this example, use /
      $.get("/")
      .fail(function () {
        // add an error element to the page
        console.log('Error');
      })
      .done(function () {
        // empty the table containing the data and rerender
        console.log('Success');
      })
      .always(function () {
        // puppeteer can now continue and check for error
        console.log('Done fetching page');
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

`test.js`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));
  await page.goto('http://localhost:58080');
  // What to do to wait for the completion of the ajax call done after
  // document is ready?
  console.log('[puppeteer] Sleeping');
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  console.log('[puppeteer] Closing');
  await browser.close();
});
```

`serve.js`:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(error, content) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        response.end(content, 'utf-8');
    });
}).listen(58080, 'localhost');
```

In one terminal:

```
node serve.js
```

In another:

```
node test.js
```

Output:

```
[puppeteer] Sleeping
Fetching page
Success
Done fetching page
[puppeteer] Closing
```

I want puppeteer to wait for the point where "Done fetching page" is printed without a preset timeout. I control the source code to the page itself, so any ideas accepted, even those that require changes to the target server. For example, if I add a hidden DOM element after the end of the Ajax call, I can use `await page.waitForSelector(cssSelector);`. I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: It sounds like waitForResponse is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @pguardiario This is indeed what I needed!

Comment: If you post an answer I can accept it

Comment: YW. I'll let you do it, just post whatever code you ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe puppeteer has a load event you can hook into.

So something like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));
  page.on('load', await () => { //set listener before you go to the page.
     // Now do something...
  });
  await page.goto('http://localhost:58080');
  // What to do to wait for the completion of the ajax call done after
  // document is ready?
  console.log('[puppeteer] Sleeping');
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  console.log('[puppeteer] Closing');
  await browser.close();
});
```

Comment: I get an `SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list` at the line `page.on('load', await () =>` ... Also, the ajax call will begin, and certainly complete long after the page has loaded, so that doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Well I did not test it, so I can't be sure of the exact syntax. Also, based upon what I'm understanding, the html doc that gets loaded from the page.goto statement is doing another Ajax call you're waiting for before responding. That's fine, the onload event should wait till the page is finished with all it's Ajax calls before it fires the event. But there seems to be other ways of doing it as well: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/598 also waitForNavigation is another method that could help.

Comment: According to the docs the syntax is `page.once('load', () => console.log('Page loaded!'));` I did this, and as I expected it is fired way before my ajax call even starts. As I explained, my call begins AFTER the page has loaded. It is itself registered on `$(document).ready`.